# Is there a way to use the function union on SQL and know from where each unique row comes from which table?

Tags: sql, union

I am trying to find the similarities and dissimilarity of two tables, most of the rows are the exact same but some aren't.
I have created a new table where I have used the function UNION but I would like to know from which table the unique rows come from.

thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first performing an union on both of the table, then using exclusive join on both source tables.

For instance on MS SQL SERVER :

**Data :**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_A(
  ID INT,
  NAME NVARCHAR(128));
  
  CREATE TABLE TEST_B(
  ID INT,
  NAME NVARCHAR(128));
  
  INSERT INTO TEST_A(ID,NAME) VALUES
  (1,'A'),
  (2,'B'),
  (3,'C'),
  (4,'E')
  
  INSERT INTO TEST_B(ID,NAME) VALUES
  (1,'A'),
  (2,'B'),
  (3,'D')
```

**Query :**

```
WITH UNIONED_TABLES AS (
  SELECT 'From TEST_A' Source_table, ID, Name
  FROM TEST_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'From TEST_B' Source_table, ID, NAME
  FROM TEST_B)
 
SELECT UT.Source_table, UT.ID, UT.NAME FROM UNIONED_TABLES UT
LEFT JOIN Test_A A ON
   UT.ID = A.ID AND
   UT.NAME = A.NAME AND
   UT.Source_table = 'From TEST_B'
LEFT JOIN Test_B B ON
   UT.ID = B.ID AND
   UT.NAME = B.NAME AND
   UT.Source_table = 'From TEST_A'
WHERE 
   A.ID IS NULL AND 
   B.ID IS NULL
```

**Results :**

```
Source_table    ID  NAME
From TEST_A      3     C
From TEST_A      4     E
From TEST_B      3     D
```

Try it online :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/248dd6/31

Comment: This method will add all the rows from both tables, but what I am looking for is to create a new table with only the distinct rows that occur in one table but not the other.  for example if table A has the value of 1,2,3. and table B has the value of 2,3,4. I would like to create table C  that only shows the values of 1"from table A", 4 "from table B" and to stay from which table it came from.

Comment: Ok, I edited my query accordingly, using exclusive joins. There could be simpler solutions that I am not aware of though.